# Как сделать плавное увеличение линии при скроле?

Tags: css, вёрстка, svg

вот ее svg код
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<svg width="1340" height="200" viewBox="0 0 1340 200" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M1379.4 199.527C1358.02 59.0626 1039.53 63.6007 794.527 73.6007C550.623 83.556 45 103 1.5271 0.600692" stroke="#574E56" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
</svg>
```

**Вопрос , какие свойства сделать , что бы изначально она не была видна, а при добавление класса плавно прорисовывалась**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как обычно получаем path измеряем его длину ...и всё это на js

```js
var path = document.querySelector('#path');
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength;
path.getBoundingClientRect();
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
  var scrollPercentage = (document.documentElement.scrollTop + document.body.scrollTop) / (document.documentElement.scrollHeight - document.documentElement.clientHeight);
  var drawLength = pathLength * scrollPercentage;
  path.style.strokeDashoffset = pathLength - drawLength;
  if (scrollPercentage >= 50) {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = "none";

  } else {
    path.style.strokeDasharray = pathLength + ' ' + pathLength;
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 1000px;
}


#svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  transform: translateX(-50%)scale(3);
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1340 200" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg">
<path d="M1379.4 199.527C1358.02 59.0626 1039.53 63.6007 794.527 73.6007C550.623 83.556 45 103 1.5271 0.600692" stroke="#574E56" stroke-width="2" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="red" stroke-width="2" id="path"/>
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://css-tricks.com/scroll-drawing/)